# AWS IoT scaling issues and metrics for monitoring IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-iot

I am using AWS IoT Service.

When a device sends a registration message to MQTT broker, I have a rule to store it in a SQS queue.
A Lambda function is triggered, when the message is added to the Queue. The `Thing` is created for the device and it's certificate is registered.

While carrying out the load testing, I observed that, after some time, the incoming messages are not received on the AWS MQTT broker and are not processed.

I  have written some test clients which run on EC2 instances to simulate the MQTT clients.

If I restart the test clients after some time, again I can see the messages coming to AWS IoT.

I am not sure, if this is the issue of MQTT broker or if it is the issue with the clients running on EC2 instances.

I can think of possible issues because of limits on AWS IoT ,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot

I want to know what are the possible AWS IoT matrices, I need to monitor for this or which IoT specific alarms I need to configure?

Is it a possible issue on EC2 side? ( maybe network out bytes per second, etc.)

There is another load testing scenario, in which I am not doing registration of devices, but just capturing the connect or disconnect events. In this case, I am not observing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, there is some limits about AWS IoT.

```
  API                  Transactions per Second
CreateCertificateFromCsr    15
CreateDynamicThingGroup 5
CreateJob   10
CreatePolicy    10
CreatePolicyVersion 10
CreateRoleAlias 10
CreateThing 15
```

Generally, AWS API throws Exception when it run over limts.
How about catch Exception?

If you want to check EC2 network issue, use some command ( netstat, tcpdump, ... )

Comment: I also think probably the issue is, we are crossing the AWS IoT limits,  I can see an error message in the Cloudwatch logs - [ERROR] EVENT:MQTT Client Connect MESSAGE:Connect Status: CLIENT_ERROR Failure reason:throttled .       I am not sure, if we can set up cloudwatch alarms on the IoT APIs.